# When awarding xp, is the summoner's eidolon counted as a separate party member with respect to xp division?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, experience-points, summoner, eidolon

Under **Exact XP** on p.399 of the *Core Rulebook*, it states that the XP for the encounter should be tallied and then divided by the number of party members. Each party member is then awarded this amount of XP.

My question is:

**Do I count the summoner's eidolon when doing this calculation? Or is the eidolon lumped in with the summoner?**

I'm assuming that the eidolon's XP is tracked separately from the summoner's rather than his level being slaved-- I could be wrong about that!

Comment: Although it may not initially seem relevant, you may nonetheless be interested in answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61806/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119340/8610).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, Eidolons don't count separately for experience and don't have experience in their own right

The [Eidolon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons) is a class feature of the summoner and the abilities of the Eidolon are derived from the Summoner's level and class features, not independently:

> An eidolon’s abilities are determined by the summoner’s level and by the choices made using its evolution pool.

The Eidolon improves when the Summoner levels up, and just as summoned creatures as from the Summon Monster etc. spells don't count as members of the party when it comes to tallying up experience, the summoned Eidolon isn't considered separate to the Summoner who brings it to the table when accounting for experience or encounter difficulty.

Answer (score 6):

Just like a Druid's animal companion, Summoned Monsters or Natures Allies, or Familiars, Eidolons are part of a class feature, and are therefore considered part of the owning character from the point of view of encounter or party composition. In a similar fashion, an enemy NPC Summoner is not given a challenge rating separate to his Eidolon - the Eidolon is part of the summoner's basic capabilities.

Sadly, I can't think of anywhere that this is explicitly spelled out in the rules.

Comment: I was going off of the fact that Hero Lab allows me to award xp to the eidolon... i'm the absence of facts, false evidence is king! Thanks. :)

Comment: Hero Lab is a useful tool, but...at the end of the day, it is not a reliable rules source. I've not actually used Hero Lab much, but I expect they just never thought to lock off the XP entry area.

Comment: HeroLab treats any creature like it is a character. You could award XP to monsters too.... even if they have no levels!