# When an Ooze splits, does it lose max HP or just current HP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Taken from the entry for the [Black Pudding](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/blackPudding.html):

> Split (Ex) Slashing and piercing weapons deal no damage to a black pudding. Instead, the creature splits into two identical puddings, **each with half of the original's current hit points** (round down). A pudding with 10 hit points or less cannot be further split and dies if reduced to 0 hit points.

(Emphasis mine)

When this occurs, is the maximum HP of the two "output" oozes

- A) Equal to the original Ooze's maximum HP
- B) Equal to their new current HP (half of the original Ooze's current HP)
- C) Determined some other way?